# Read a logfile in perl and find the value within square brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I have a `logfile.txt` which has the execution log of a certain testcase. A sample of this file is as shown below. Although it has many other lines but i have removed them for the sake of simplicity.

In this `logfile.txt`, my final goal is to get the hex value within the square brackets in the last line.

I have written a sample code in `PERL` to search for the last line and print but i'm unable to formulate the regex to get the desired value.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $logfile = "/path/to/logfile.txt";
open ( IN1 , $logfile) or die "Cannot find the file $logfile \n";
while (<IN1>)
    {
        chomp ($_);
        print $_ if ($_ =~ m/The job has completed/i);
    }
close (IN1);
```

**INPUT**

```
   > cat logfile.txt

Waiting for the completion of job..
.
.
.
.
.


The job has completed, returning [0x0]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0x0
```

Comment: Try it like this `\[\K0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+(?=\])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $log_fh, '<', 'logfile.txt' or die $!;

while (<$log_fh>) {
  print $1 if /The job has completed.+\[(.+)\]/;
}
```

I've used parentheses (`(...)`) to "capture" whatever appears between `[` and `]`. When the regex matches, the captured text will be stored in `$1`.

Note, I've also updated your code to use a more modern idiom for opening files. I a) use a lexical filehandle, b) use the three-argument version of `open()` and c) check the return value from `open()` and kill the program if it fails.

Comment: @Yash: Well, I know it works! But, more importantly, did you understand it? :-)

Comment: yes i understood it. just wanted to clarify that in the above method isn't it mandatory to `close` the file handle ?

Comment: @Yash: Well, it's never mandatory to `close()` a filehandle. But one of the advantages of using a lexical variable is that the filehandle will be closed automatically as the variable goes out of scope (or, in this case, when the program ends).

Answer (score 4):

To match the last line including the start of you sentence, you could use:

```
^The job has completed,.*?\[\K0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+(?=\])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YSOiLk/1)

That will match:

- `^The job has completed,` Match literally from the start of the string
- `.*?` Match any character non greedy
- `\[\K` Match an opening bracket and forget what was matched using `\K`
- `0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+` Match a hexadecimal number
- `(?=\])` Positive lookahead to verify what follows is a closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl one-liner

```
$ perl -lne ' if(eof) { /.*\[(.*)\].*/ and print "Hex = $1" } ' logfile.txt
Hex = 0x0
$
```

More shorter.. Thanks @Dave Cross

```
$ perl -lne ' if(eof) { /\[(.*)\]/ and print "Hex = $1" } ' logfile.txt
Hex = 0x0
$
```

If you want to make sure "The job has completed" in last line, then

```
$  perl -lne ' if(eof) { /The job has completed.*\[(.*)\].*/ and print "Hex = $1" } ' logfile.txt
Hex = 0x0
$
```

Comment: There's no need for the first or last `.*` in your regex.